# Symfony form always give me "This value should not be blank." message

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'm having trouble with a simple login form made by Symfony. Here is the controller code:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request){
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('userID', 'text', array('label' => 'UserID'))
        ->add('password', 'password', array('label' => 'Password'))
        ->add('ricorda', 'checkbox', array(
                "required" => false,
                "mapped" => false
        ))
        ->add('login', 'submit')->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        Debug::dump($_POST$user);
        /*if($form->isValid()){

        }*/
        return $this->render('TDDumbFEBundle:Default:auth.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

and here the entity class user, in which form data should be stored and then validated:

```
class User{

    private $userID;

    private $password;

    public function getUserID(){
        return $this->userID;
    }

    public function getPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setUserID($userID){
        $this->$userID = $userID;
    }

    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->$password = $password;
    }
}
```

finaly, the constraints:

```
properties:
  userID:
    - NotBlank: ~
  password:
    - NotBlank: ~
```

Well, don't know why but whatever I type in the userID and password input fields, I always get a

`This value should not be blank.`

message. If I use the `Debug::dump()` method on the user object, I find out that all properties are empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo.

```
public function setUserID($userID){
    $this->$userID = $userID;          // *** Change to $this->userID = $userID
}

public function setPassword($password){
    $this->$password = $password;      // *** Change to $this->password = $password;
}
```